# RabbitMq queue filling up

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We have a rabbitmq queue with multiple java programs on different linux servers consuming from that queue. Sometimes the queue fills up such that we need to purge the queue and loose messages.

Looking at the CPU usage on the client machines, the clients do not seem to be the bootleneck. Their usage is at about 25% on a multicore box. Hence I guess the network might be the bottleneck. Is there anyway I can see this from the management interface of rabbitmq?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing?  Consumers are not able to processes fast enough?

Comment: Well I am wondering if it is the consumers or if it is the network which is not fast enough.

Comment: It also might be IO performance degradation due to various issues. Without specific details like RabbitMQ version, OS type and version (sometimes even system libs versions matter), avg message size, queues number, messages flow, filesystem type, discs specs, raid, another software run in parallel,  etc. it is hard to guess what cause the problem. The whole question looks a bit offtopic for StackOverflow while it is more about debbuging without specifying steps and env to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I would take a look at this blog post and `basic.qos` usage as well: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/11/some-queuing-theory-throughput-latency-and-bandwidth/

Answer (score 1):

Your clients may actually be losing connection to RabbitMQ. I have run into similar problems when after some prolonged period of clients being inactive - for example when the producers don't fill the queue for a long time, the clients have nothing to consume -  the TCP connection between clients and RabbitMQ can get interrupted, usually by a load balancer but the client never finds out that the connection was dropped. Here is how to test for it: when you find your clients are no longer consuming from the queue, kill the clients and restart them and see if the queue starts to reduce the message backlog. If yes, that is exactly your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed we do have load balancers between rabbit and the consumers. I will check for this.